# Colouring country in ArcGIS dynamically

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm new to ArcGIS looking to implement dynamic maps via javascript on my website which loads on a country profile page of the selected country.

The code below loads the world map with the selected country zoomed into, what i'd like is to have the country also in a different shade, just to make it stand out for the rest.

Any idea how to get this done? Thanks in advance

```
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Map) {
            map = new Map("mapDiv",
            {
                zoom: 6,
                basemap: "oceans",
                "extent": new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":/*west*/,"ymin":/*south*/,"xmax":/*east*/,"ymax":/*west*/,"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}})
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **DynamicLayer** which is added in ArcGIS Server 10.1.

See [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/00sq/00sq000000n1000000.htm) and [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/renderer_dynamic_layer_change_attribute.html) for details.